# Mojave (MacOs) - How to toggle between windows of same application?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

I am using MacBook Pro , macOS Mojave (10.14.4) . I am not able to toggle between windows of same application .

I tried Command + BackTick but its not working . Tried to change shortcut for "Move focus to next window" , but no luck .

Thanks

Comment: Command + Backtick is definitely the default. I do it with Safari daily. I know that may not help your situation much... Silly question, but are you sure they’re separate windows of the same program? Could you try opening multiple safari windows and pressing Command + Backtick? I doubt it’ll work given what you’ve said, but it feels like a decent sanity check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the other windows of your same application are minimized.

Sadly, there's no keyboard shortcut that can show windows of same application if those windows are minimized. Command + Backtick only works on visible windows.

You can bring up the other minimized windows by right clicking the app's icon on the dock, then select the minimized window

**UPDATE April 20 2019**

Found an application that can bring up minimized windows of same application. App is [HyperSwitch](https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch). You still need to do command + tab, then wait a second, a preview of all windows of same application will be shown. Then you can press command + backtick to switch to all windows of same application, even the minimized ones.

Found it on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to bring up minimized windows without using 3rd-party app is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> (Mission Control's Application windows)

I feel <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> should be fixed, it should show minimized windows too. Or yellow traffic light button should default to hidden instead of minimized, so <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> can show all windows of same app

Note: <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> also works even if all of the windows of an application are minimized

I now disabled <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> on my machine. It's confusing to have two shortcuts for basically achieving the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Another good option: AltTab

Use <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to toggle/switch among applications

To toggle/switch among windows of same application, use: <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

You can change the <kbd>option</kbd> to <kbd>command</kbd> on AltTab, doing that, AltTab will override the default <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> app switcher of macOS

Download at: https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/

seen from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=468&v=W1L2V09VXwY

Comment: This app is a life-saver! Works exactly as `Alt+Tab` in Win10. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on "Active Corners" you can make windows of same application pop up if you pull your mouse to the far corner you have activated and assigned to "program windows".....

Sorry for the messy terminology, my system language is set to danish, so the english terms I use here are just guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I had a similar problem, maybe it helps someone in the future.

For me, it was fixed by reassigning the shortcut for "Move focus to next window" (to the same key combination as before). Not sure why, but it worked for me.